# redirect all sub-domain to the main domain except some sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this code in htaccess to redirect all sub-domains to the main domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I want to exclude some sub-domains like test.example.com so I edited the code like this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But it doesn't work it redirects the test.exmple.com to the main domain example.com/test

So how to edit this code to exclude test from the redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match domain name you need to use variable `HTTP_HOST`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```